# SPSS tracks a variable as missing in some analyses but not others?

Tags: spss

When running a Reliability analysis I got en error warning that there were too few cases for the analysis. My dataset has no missing cases or missing values. I tried re-importing the dataset from Excel which didn't fix the issue, nor did importing as a CSV.

I identified the problematic variable (points_16359) using missing values analysis:
[image]

However there are no missing data for that variable in the dataset; when I run a frequency analysis I get:

[image]

And even more strange, the MVA on just that same variable shows no missing cases:

[image]

I only have one recordset active. I restarted SPSS and repeated all the above with the same results.

I did find a workaround with this syntax:

```
RECODE points_16539 (SYSMIS=SYSMIS) (ELSE=Copy) INTO recd_16539.
```

But I have no idea what is causing the problem, and since this is part of an automated analysis I routinely do, it breaks my syntax. Does anyone have an explanation or better workaround? Thanks in advance.